# NoSQL - DynamoDB - Designing Tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, non-relational-database, nosql

Sorry for my noob question, I’m newbie in NoSQL.

My case, if in Relationship Database, I have 3 table as:

```
 Book     ( **Book_ID**, Book_Name, Page_Number ).

 Category ( **Category_ID**, Category_Name ).

 Author   ( **Author_ID**, Author_Name ).
```

A Book has only one Author and one Category, but an Author got many book, and one Category

also got many book too. [Author] --(1-------n)-- [Book] --(n-------1)-- [Category]

Relationship Database we just create foreign key in Book as

```
 Book( **Book_ID**, Book_Name, Page_Number, *Category_ID*, *Author_ID* )
```

, but we can’t do that with NoSQL.

So I really can’t solve that how to Designing table(s) with NoSQL to answer both query is:

```
 1. Show me all the books belong to one of Category.
(Select * From  Book, Category 
 Where Book.Category_ID=Category.Category_ID and Category.Category_ID="X")

 2. Show me all the books belong to one of Author.
(Select * From  Book, Author 
 Where Book.Author_ID=Author.Author_ID and Author.Author_ID="Y")
```

I mean do we got any ways to design table(s)/model follow NoSQL which still responds me both query above?

I use DynamoDB to store database, do I was wrong to chose it?

I try this (i cant post Image) : s6.postimg.org/z44997j0x/Basic_4.jpg

Thank everyone was give your precious time to read and help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't add all attributes to your objects such as a if book has one (or more?) author(s) and one or more categories.

From the questions you asked it's not clear if you want to query 
a) one category precisely VS given a category X, give me all books that have this category.

If you edit your question to be more precise it will be easier to answer.

Regardless, I've asked a [similar noob question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9179605/how-to-model-student-classes-with-dynamodb-nosql) about DynamoDB/NoSQL 3 years ago - perhaps it will help you as well.

Comment: Thank you Chen Harel, i was edited my question hope it more clearly, i had read your link, but my problem is we got 3 table relationship with together [Author] --(1-------n)-- [Book] --(n-------1)-- [Category].
Again Thank you for answer my question!!!